# What is an alias with parentheses (something like "FROM ... a(m)")?

Tags: postgresql

Someone answered to [a question I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945489/generate-table-with-random-values-from-other-tables-in-postgresql) about generating a table with random values using existing tables (still struggling with it). And the answer has something like this:

```
select uuid_generate_v4(), a."Account", tns."Name", tvs."Value"
from generate_series(1, 10) x(rn)
left join (
    select "Account", row_number() over(order by random()) rn from "AccountSamples"
) a on a.rn = x.rn
```

I don't understand the x(rn) part, it seems like an alias but I don't understand why does it have an "rn" inside of the parenthesis, and the parenthesis itself is new to me, is rn another alias or a special keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [column alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.7.2). I think the simplest way to explain this is with two queries:

```
select *
from generate_series(1, 10) x(rn);

select *
from generate_series(1, 10) x(foo);
```

Both will generate a table with the alias `x` but the first one will have a single column named `rn` while the column in the second one will be named `foo`. See this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/syWxnFjEvuBiYZvtZsDmwY/2).

You could remove the `(rn)` but then the column would need to be referenced as `x.x` which is likely to be confusing.

Comment: also see [VALUES Lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-values.html)